# Can anyone explain the difference between these two regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+$/
```

vs

```
/[^a-zA-Z]+$/
```

Comment: You can discover this yourself: http://www.regexr.com/

Comment: [Position anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) vs. [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Comment: You can google for a 'regex tester' like this (http://regexpal.com/) to help see what your regex matches.

Answer (score 2):

The `^` at the start of the expression means "Anchor at the beginning of the string".

The `^` inside the *character class* `[]` expression means `negate`.

So `/^[a-zA-Z]$/` matches a string that consists entirely (from beginning to end) of upper case and lower case alphabetic characters, while `/[^a-zA-Z]$/` matches the "end of the string that does not consist of alphabetic characters" (for example, numbers at the end of the string).

```
this is a string       -- matches neither 
                          (contains non alphabetic, but doesn't end in it)

this is a number: 123  -- second expression matches ': 123'
                          (string ends in non-alphabetic characters)

this                   -- first expression matches  'this' 
                          (string contains only alphabetic characters)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case 1 the `^` indicates the beginning of the input. Case two negates the term.

Case 1: From beginning(`^`) to end (`$`) match `a-zA-Z` 0 or more(`+`) times

Case 2: Match everything that does not(`^`) end(`$`) with `a-zA-Z` 0-x(`+`) chars

Answer (score 0):

`/^[a-zA-Z]+$/`

means that the string should 
`^`: start with
`[a-zA-Z]`: lower case or upper case alpha character
`+`: At least one of the previous, in this case at least one of alpha character
`$`: Should end with a uppper case or lower case alpha character

Exmaple: 
OnLyUpPeRaNdLoWeRcAsEaNdNoSpAcEs

`/[^a-zA-Z]+$/`

`[^a-zA-Z]`: **NOT** an upper case or lower case character
`+`: At least one of the previous, in this case at least one character **but NOT** of upper case or lower case alpha character
`$`: Should end with a `none` upper case or lower case alpha character

Example:
123456789
anything12345 <-- this works because we didn't specify how the string should start but we know that it should end with a non alpha character

Comment: /^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test('AbRcD');
console --> true
/[^a-zA-Z]+$/.test('Abf3498');
console --> true

Comment: @user3475797 yes that's true because we didn't specify how the second expression starts unlike the first expression